# Calculating the mean of a part of a column of a pandas dataframe ignoring nans

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, mean

I have trouble calculating the mean of a part of a column in a pandas dataframe.
I need to divide my dataframe into sub-windows, and I need the mean for every of these smaller windwows for specific columns.

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
array2 = np.array([[x[:,0].mean()]
                for x in np.array_split(array1, 10)])
```

So at the moment I divide array1 into 10 subarrays. Now my problem: for some reason i get "nan" as the solution for some of the means. This is probably due to the reason that there must be some nan values in array1. How can I only calculate the mean for not-nan values while I do not remove the nans at all from array1? Is this possible? Thank you very much!:)

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you could use (which should also work with `NaNs`):

```
df.groupby(df.index//10)['column'].mean()
```

This works if the dataframe's index is a `pd.RangeIndex`. Otherwise you can do:

```
df.groupby(pd.RangeIndex(df.shape[0])//10)['column'].mean()
```

---

As a side note, for computing the mean of a numpy array containing `NaNs`, you have [`numpy.nanmean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html)

Comment: You would want to do `df.reset_index().groupby...` so that //10 work correctly in any case.

Comment: Don't think so, if the index is a normal pd.RangeIndex, this should work fine @oleg

Comment: In my suggestion, `df = df.reset_index()` should be done before groupby operation, apparently, so that the index were affected.

Comment: Not sure how exactly np.arange is working underneath, but as I checked it won't work with DatetimeIndex either (throwing TypeError: invalid type promotion).
If messing with the original index is a problem, one can always recover it from 'index' column afterwards.

Comment: @OlegO - I forget for length `df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//10)['col'].mean()`

Comment: Thank you very much!:) I just tried it, but I get an array with the size of my original data. I don't know if I did something wrong but I kinda just copied your code :'D

Comment: The output is not an array though. It is a dataframe @zaaariina if you want an array of means just add `df.groupby(pd.RangeIndex(df.shape[0])//10)['column'].mean().values.tolist()`, let me know if that's what you want